# How to download in headless mode with selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I have a test running to download files from a website, the files download okay without the headless argument `chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')` but as soon as I add this line nothing downloads, are there more flags I need to add?

Answer (score 2):

It's a known issue (rather feature than a bug). If you are using python you can use: [this](https://github.com/shawnbutton/PythonHeadlessChrome/blob/master/driver_builder.py) solution.

If you want to read more, please visit bugs.chromium.org discussion: [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696481)